# generate a random number from log normal distribution in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, normal-distribution

i am using MS Visual studio 2010.

and now I would like to generate a random number in the range from 3 to 200 by a log normal distribution.

I heard that "central limit theorem" can convert the uniform distribution to normal distribution, but it seem too much work for me, because my range has 198 numbers :

```
a = random(MaxRange+1); // mean i have to write this for 198 time???!!!!
x = (a+.......)/198 ; //this will obtain a number which is a normal distribution right???
```

then, may i just write

```
y = log (x);  // and is this mean that y is log normal distribution????
```

thanks for answering my question....

Comment: I think that the latest C++11 standard has library functions and headers for that purpose. (and perhaps Boost has some also).

Comment: Arbitrary distribution may be obtained by applying the inverse distribution function to uniformly distributed random variable. Wy not to use this universal approach?

Comment: If the range is between 3 and 200, you will not be able to use a log-normal distribution.

Answer (score 3):

Well random will give you uniformly distributed random numbers as you said correctly. In order to generator variables with normal distribution you can use the [Box-Muller transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) which is simple to implement.

Next you need to generate your lognormal variable `v`. By calculating `v = exp(mu + sig * n)` where `n` is your normal distributed random variable.

I don't quite understand what you mean with range 3 to 200 as the lognormal distribution has support ]0,inf[

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at the `lognormal_distribution` class inside [Boost random library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_random.html). See [here](http://quantlib.org/slides/dima-boost-intro.pdf) for an example of how to generate numbers from a given distribution (you have to instantiate a `boost::variate_generator` with a given random number generator plus an instance of the distribution).

Answer (score 0):

Further to Azrael3000's answer,

Let the lognormal variable lgn is generated as lgn = exp(mu + sig * stdn) where stdn is the standard normal variable, then we must note that the mu and sig for the equation above are given as:

*if m and v are the mean and variance of the non-logarithmized sample values*

[image: mu equation]

[image: sigma^2 equation]

Ref: [wiki - Log-normal_distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)